# Kubernetes - How to know which minions are hosting Pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-health-check

I have a 6 minion cluster and would like to know how many of these minions are actually hosting pods at any given time. Is there a specific command for that ? Right now Im using a very generic command.

```
kubectl get po | grep Running > RUNNING.txt
for i in `cat RUNNING.txt `; do kubectl describe po $i; done | grep "Started container with docker
```

"

Any direct command to fetch the info I want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `-o wide`:

```
kubectl get pod -o wide
```

Comment: :) If you want to use this information in scripts it's worth reading https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/kubectl/list-all-running-container-images/#list-containers-using-a-go-template-instead-of-jsonpath

Answer (score 0):

This command will print all the nodes that have pods running on them:

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.spec.nodeName} {end}' | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq
```